# NodeJS with DynamoDB throws error "AttributeValue may not contain an empty string"

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I had a problem with the fact that DynamoDB cannot accept empty strings as value in attributes.
I always had to check in the front end if there is an empty string value otherwise the API call would fail due to the error "An AttributeValue may not contain an empty string" that Dynamo DB would throw.

I was wandering if there is a recursive function that would remove the attributes that are not valid according to DynamoDB in order for the putItem or update request in DynamoDB to work.

Answer (score 39):

Latest update on [Jan 3 2017 Merge #1283](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/pull/1283) updated the [AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html) [constructor-property](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#constructor-property) to allow for empty values by putting the flag `convertEmptyValues` into the options field of the client object.

Example:

```
const DynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient( {
    convertEmptyValues: true
} );
```

**Notable issues**

- [DynamoDB.DocumentClient should support empty string properties #833](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/833)
- [Respect convertEmptyValues option for Maps and Lists in the DynamoDB document client #1281](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/pull/1281)
- [Fix/doc client empty nested members #1283](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/pull/1283)
- [AWS Forum threadID #90137](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=90137)
- [Empty Attribute would cause ValidationException for DynamoDb boto/boto3 #1035](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1035)

Comment: does this exist for python sdk?

Comment: It doesn't _look_ like Python supports this. Quick search on the documentation says `Attribute values must not be null; string and binary type attributes must have lengths greater than zero; and set type attributes must not be empty. Requests that contain empty values will be rejected with a ValidationException exception.`

- https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html

With no "convert" keyword found

Comment: This works perfectly, this should be accepted as answer :)

Comment: For Python, I handled that snag with a custom recursion, worked for your data schema. https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1035#issuecomment-516093427

Comment: As of June 2020, DynamoDB now supports empty strings natively. Make sure to turn off `convertEmptyValues` or else empty strings will be converted to NULL. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62166912/1457398

Answer (score 1):

**June 2020 Update:**

DynamoDB now supports empty string values for non-key attributes: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/05/amazon-dynamodb-now-supports-empty-values-for-non-key-string-and-binary-attributes-in-dynamodb-tables/

In order to have consistent behavior, make sure that the client does *not* have `{ convertEmptyValues: true }`, or else these attributes will be saved as NULL as opposed to an empty String.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create a recursive function that checks every attribute in an object returning it without those invalid attribute values according to DynamoDB.

```
function clean(obj) {
    return function remove(current) {
        _.each(current, function(value, key) {
            if (_.isUndefined(value) || _.isNull(value) || _.isNaN(value) ||
                (_.isString(value) && _.isEmpty(value)) ||
                (_.isObject(value) && _.isEmpty(remove(value)))) {

                delete current[key];
            }
        });
        if (_.isArray(current)) _.without(current, undefined);
        return current;
    }(_.clone(obj));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't keep a document attribute when there is no value.
Here is how I handle empty string values for optional attributes with PutItem.

```
user: {
  Username: 'jdoe',
  Name: 'John Doe',
  Description: 'Fake user'
}
```

You update the value if it's not empty, delete the attribute otherwise:

```
  const params = {
    Key: {
      Username: {
        S: user.Username
      }
    },
    AttributeUpdates: {},
    TableName: 'Users',
  };

  if (user.hasOwnProperty('Description')) {
    params.AttributeUpdates.Description = (user.Description === '')
    ? { Action: 'DELETE' }
    : { Action: 'PUT', Value: { S: user.Description } };
  }

  return db.updateItem(params)
    .promise()
```

In dynamoDB:

```
user: {
  Username: 'jdoe',
  Name: 'John Doe'
}
```