# How to pass an empty string as value of a field in dynamodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to do a post request with the following json data. But i need one field ie 'notes' to pass as an empty string value. When I am passing like that, an error is getting :

> 'One or more parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not contain an empty string'.

How can I fix this issue?

```
//json data which i need to post
  {
  "storeId": "106",
  "addressId": "1",
  "managerId": "1",
  "name": "Syammohan",
  "contactNo": "9656985685",
  "notes": "",
  "bookingType": "Weddding Consult",
  "bookingDate": "2019-05-02",
  "bookingTime": "09:00 am"
}

function bookingDone(employee) {
  var {

    storeId,
    addressId,
    managerId,
    name,
    contactNo,
    notes,
    bookingType,
    bookingStatus,
    bookingTime
  } = req.body

  console.log("notes", notes);

  const params = {
    TableName: "Booking",

    Item: {
      id: id,
      storeId: storeId,
      addressId: addressId,
      managerId: managerId,
      name: name,
      contactNo: contactNo,
      notes: notes,
      bookingType: bookingType,
      bookingStatus: bookingStatus,
      bookingDate: bookingDate,
      bookingTime: bookingTime,
      employeeId: employee.id

    },

  };

  docClient.put(params, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(400).json({ error: 'Could not create booking' });
    }
    // queue.push(JSON.stringify({ event: 'booking.booking.created', model: { 'Bookings': params.Item } }));
    res.send(params.Item)
    // res.json({ id, name, info });

  });
}
```

Comment: dynamo doesn't accept empty string, why not put some generic string or leave the field altogether?

Comment: Are you aware of that DDB is noSql?

Comment: Your problem is not NodeJS related. Can't you set `"notes": null`?

Comment: From docs `Attribute values cannot be null. String and Binary type attributes must have lengths greater than zero.`

Comment: `"notes": !notes ? " " : notes`

Comment: As of June 2020, DynamoDB now supports empty strings natively. Make sure to turn off `convertEmptyValues` or else empty strings will be converted to NULL. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62166912/1457398

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes Dynamodb cannot accepts empty string. So edit the aws configuration

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
     convertEmptyValues: true
  });

This works!

Comment: Dynamo supports empty strings starting May 2020: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/05/amazon-dynamodb-now-supports-empty-values-for-non-key-string-and-binary-attributes-in-dynamodb-tables/

Answer (score 8):

Amazon DynamoDB now supports empty values for non-key String and Binary attributes in DynamoDB tables
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61909830/7532347

Comment: Thanks for the link! Does the user need to update anything? I'm still getting the ValidationException error when I pass null to an optional

Comment: This repeats the identical update [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61880991/1357094)

Answer (score 7):

A map of attributes and their values. Each entry in this map consists of an attribute name and an attribute value. Attribute values must not be null; string and binary type attributes must have lengths greater than zero; and set type attributes must not be empty. Requests that contain empty values will be rejected with a ValidationException exception.

You can solve the problem by defining a function to remove empty string from the object like

```
function removeEmptyStringElements(obj) {
  for (var prop in obj) {
    if(obj[prop] === '') {// delete elements that are empty strings
      delete obj[prop];
    }
  }
  return obj;
}
removeEmptyStringElements(req.body);
```

This will remove the empty attributes from your object.

If your object contains nested object then use the following function

```
function removeEmptyStringElements(obj) {
  for (var prop in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[prop] === 'object') {// dive deeper in
      removeEmptyStringElements(obj[prop]);
    } else if(obj[prop] === '') {// delete elements that are empty strings
      delete obj[prop];
    }
  }

removeEmptyStringElements(req.body)
```

Answer (score 5):

Empty values in non-key string/binary attributes is now supported - [AWS announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/05/amazon-dynamodb-now-supports-empty-values-for-non-key-string-and-binary-attributes-in-dynamodb-tables/?sc_channel=sm&sc_campaign=DB_Blog&sc_publisher=TWITTER&sc_country=DynamoDB&sc_geo=GLOBAL&sc_outcome=awareness&trk=ddbemptyvalues_051820_TWITTER&sc_category=Amazon%20DynamoDB&linkId=88894636)